# Get Option inside PHP

Tags: php

I have a theme options panel in Wordpress I created. I am trying to pull an API key from the field. But I cannot echo PHP within PHP. How would I do this looking at code below. The top code is what it needs to be after I fill in feild in options panel. The bottom is code I need to work. Hope this makes sense.

```
<?php
require_once('class.php');
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$api = new MCAPI('77777777777777777777777777777777');   
?>
```

Below is what I am trying to do with code

```
<?php
require_once('class.php');
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$api = new MCAPI('<?php $text_area = get_option    ('Mail_Chimp_API'); echo $text_area;?>');    
?>
```

Comment: eval() - Evaluate string as PHP code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

It's considered a huge security hole, so you'd probably want to find alternate ways to achieve what you need. Why don't you execute code separately and give MCAPI constructor just results?

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once('class.php');
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$text_area = get_option('Mail_Chimp_API');
$api = new MCAPI($text_area);
```

assign the variable before using it.

Comment: He does not need the variable. Less so he needs a variable called $text_area.

Comment: Yeah, he does not. I can write you 90% of code without a single variable. But I'm not really sure if it is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need

```
<?php
require_once('class.php');
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$api = new MCAPI(get_option ('Mail_Chimp_API'));   
?>
```

You do not need to "echo" your data per se. I suggest learning a bit of PHP from either W3Schools or other online resource. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I tried that code..I get an error.  --> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_option()

Comment: If get_option is undefined, then you're not running the code in WordPress.